# Azure Website WebJobs - Can they use the site's app settings or connection strings

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I'd like the webjobs to be able to pick up on updated app config settings, or connection strings without having to upload a new config file for the exe each time.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes they can pick up app config settings or connections strings. This works the same way as your Azure Websites